# Log url visits in android

Tags: android, url, logging

I hope to create an android app which can save all the url visits, including typed-in url or url visited by clicks. Can someone give me a hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general this is impossible to do without a rooted device.  While Lokesh's answer hints at the posibility of using the browser history, it is in all reality quite possible that the user will simply have used another browser.  You also don't consider the possibility of people "visiting" other URLs by using apps which display information from those URLs but don't explicitly load in a `WebView`?  (For example, the Gas Buddy app.)  To do this reliably, you will need some kind of a proxy, which can actually monitor network traffic and log it.  However, you should note that this kind of ability will not be possible without rooting the device.